# Запрос без потери символов

Tags: php, mysql

Всем привет,недавно столкнулся с такой проблемой. При запросе в базу , данные с кавычками , выводятся без них. К примеру, я в инпут пишу ТОО "Имя" и добавляю в базу. В базе слово стоит с кавычками. При запросе , слово выводится до кавычек :к примеру  ТОО (должно быть ТОО "Имя") .С помощью данного кода , заменяю кавычки на пробелы и таким образом выводится слово. `$changed= str_replace('"',' ',$row->name);` И тогда выводится целиком слово , но без кавычек. Есть ли другие способы выводить слова без потерь символов

Comment: Ничего не понял, но пусть будет [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.htmlspecialchars.php).

Comment: Ничего не понял, но пусть будет не используй eval.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте http://php.net/manual/ru/function.htmlentities.php или http://php.net/manual/ru/function.htmlspecialchars.php

При добавлении записи в бд используйте prepeared statements

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте перед запросом заэскейпить все неугодные символы, включая кавычки, через `mysql_real_escape_string()`
получится что-то навроде:

```
$myvar = "ТОО 'Имя'";
$myvar = mysql_real_escape_string($myvar);
$query = "INSERT INTO mytable VALUES('$myvar',...);"
```

Comment: Не надо рекомендовать использовать устаревшее и отключенное в свежих версиях расширение. Как минимум, надо анадлог для mysqli, а лучше использовать параметры подготовленного запроса.